# sort dataframe by other dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

Given a  df's
knn_df

```
           0          1         2          3
0  1.1565523   1.902790  1.927971  1.1530536
1   1.927971  1.1565523  1.815097  1.1530536
2   1.902790  1.1565523  1.815097   1.927971
3   1.815097   1.927971  1.902790  1.1530536
4   1.902790  1.1565523  1.815097  1.1530536
```

dates_df

```
    0   1   2   3
0   2011-11-14 02:30:00.601 2003-08-12 00:00:00.000 2003-11-30 23:00:00.000 2011-10-25 12:00:00.000
1   2003-11-30 23:00:00.000 2011-11-14 02:30:00.601 2002-08-06 00:00:00.000 2011-10-25 12:00:00.000
2   2003-08-12 00:00:00.000 2011-11-14 02:30:00.601 2002-08-06 00:00:00.000 2003-11-30 23:00:00.000
3   2002-08-06 00:00:00.000 2003-11-30 23:00:00.000 2003-08-12 00:00:00.000 2011-10-25 12:00:00.000
4   2003-08-12 00:00:00.000 2011-11-14 02:30:00.601 2002-08-06 00:00:00.000 2011-10-25 12:00:00.000
```

I have to sort the values of knn_df be the dates of the dates_df.

Every row in dates_df correspond to row in knn_df

I tried to sort like this.

```
np.argsort(dates_df.values,axis=1)[:,::-1]

array([[0, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 0, 2],
       [1, 3, 0, 2],
       [3, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 0, 2]])
```

Which give the right order of the values by columns, But when i tried to reorder

```
Sorted_knn = (knn_df.values[np.arange(len(knn_df)),
                        np.argsort(dates_df.values,axis=1)[:,::-1]])
```

I get an error

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,4)
```

I am missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[:, None]` for making two-dimensional 5x1 array for correct broadcasting:

```
a = np.argsort(dates_df.values,axis=1)[:,::-1]
b = knn_df.values[np.arange(len(knn_df))[:, None], a]
print (b)
[[1.1565523 1.1530536 1.927971  1.90279  ]
 [1.1565523 1.1530536 1.927971  1.815097 ]
 [1.1565523 1.927971  1.90279   1.815097 ]
 [1.1530536 1.927971  1.90279   1.815097 ]
 [1.1565523 1.1530536 1.90279   1.815097 ]]
```